# Why doesn't honey spoil quickly?

Tags: biochemistry

Why is it that [honey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey) can last for decades and not spoil like other foods? Is there any chemical in honey which gives rise to this amazing feat?

Comment: see http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/sugar-as-a-defence-against-bacteria

Comment: Based on Alan Boyd's link I think this is a dupe.

Comment: One reason is that sugar has a pH of 7, while honey has a pH of 3.26 to 4.48, a killing field for bacteria. Also, bees process honey by means of an enzyme called glucose oxidase, AKA 'Penicillin A' (formerly) or 'Notatin', which reduces atmospheric O2 to H2O2 (Hydrogen peroxide), forming an antimicrobial barrier on the honey surface. Also, bacteria become desiccated in honey because of the hygroscopic effects of the sugar (mostly supersaturated in honey). Basically, related, but not a duplicate question.

Comment: @daniel pls reopen the post. as J. Musser mentioned, it's definitely not a duplicate.